# Trim all Strings in a Node (Java webservice)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, dom

I am getting the XML data that is sent as part of SOAP request using a handler in webservice before unmarshalling of the request is done.

```
Node root = soapMsgContext.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFirstChild();
```

Is there to trim all the elements in the node? For instance in the below case -

```
<Person>
  <Name> J i m </Name>
  <Details>
     <age> 1 9 </age>
     <Address>
        <firstName> J i mm y </firstName>
        <lastName> An der son </lastName>
     </Address>
  </Details>
<Person>
```

must be changed to

```
<Person>
  <Name>Jim</Name>
  <Details>
     <age>19</age>
     <Address>
        <firstName>Jimmy</firstName>
        <lastName>Anderson</lastName>
     </Address>
  </Details>
<Person>
```

EDIT: Webservices framework being used is JAX-RPC.

Comment: +1 for a good question, but you might want to state which web services framework you're using?

Comment: Thanks David. I am using JAX-RPC, have edited the original post.

Comment: I don't expect any XML library to do this. An XML parser is required to report all characters that are element content. Whitespace handling (`DocumentBuilderFactory#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace`) is only relevant for whitespace between child elements. So this is handling is left to the application (which, in fact, is the only instance to know the business rules, like `Jim my Dea n`).

Comment: Thanks. One of the problems is that some of the data types is integer and when <age> 1 2 </age> is part of request an exception is being thrown while unmarshalling the data. So I wanted to remove all spaces in soap handler before unmarshalling the request.Is there a generic way to loop through all the xml elements in the DOM and trim the value?

Comment: No. I would do an `XPath` for all relevant nodes and do a manual replacement. In fact the very first thing I would do is complain to the sender to PLEASE send me a result according to the rules - that is the *whole* point of XML, otherwise formats like Json are better suited.

Comment: Are you trying to add some code to cater for badly formed requests? Where are these requests coming from? IMHO the best approach would be the get the calling end to fix the request. Is this absolutely not possible?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The requests may come from SOAP UI or Web Applications containing text area where the request could be pasted. So if there is any space in the values , I am trying trim them. Currently these requests are resulting in application exception. For instance , when space is entered in a integer field - numberformat exception is being thrown for the specific field.

Comment: Ah, this is not the request but the payload? And the payload is unsanitized user input? - That is something completely different. But then this, what you get, is a string that may or may not be XML, but it is not XML for sure. You certainly can't just unmarshal without validating and sanitizing.

Comment: Is there any defined standard for validation and sanitization? I guess validation must be done against the relevant schema - is there a way to trim spaces once the data is validated?

Comment: You get the validation for free - it is the exception you get when unmarshaling. You have to do the sanitizing by hand, because it is just unstructured data you get. If you know you have integer variables to parse you need to do the trimming on the text, maybe with regex (Note: This is NOT handling XML with Regex because it is not XML yet, just text with angular brackets!). If spaces in the names don't break the parsing I would do the trimming on those fields after parsing (on the generated object). How should there be a standard? It's unstructured text before and your rules afterwards.

Comment: Thanks his. I am doing the validation on objects after unmarshalling the request.However I wanted to see if I could trim all the text in angular brackets before unmarshalling so that some of the data issues could be avoided.

Comment: Not sure myself what the difference is between request and payload? Quite an unusual scenario to allow the user to enter an entire request as text. What if they just enter "x" and press submit? Do you get a horrible unmarshalling error? You do really need an extra stage to validate this text before the web service is called. Can you add another tier e.g. a servlet, then you can do whatever you want in that layer (remove spaces, throw back errors, etc) and only call the web service layer if the input is valid?

Comment: We are exposing this as a webservice - there might be multiple consumers which we not be aware of. I was seeing if I should be putting safegaurds in place by checking the xml text before unmarshalling. Currently there is a numberformatexception that is being thrown for this specific case.

Comment: Yes I think you need something before the web services unmarshalling. I've never used JAX-RPC so don't know exactly how to do this. Using a servlet would work but may be overkill. Maybe a JAX-RPC handler? See this link: http://java.boot.by/wsd-guide/ch04s07.html. Search the page for "Handlers let you access/modify SOAP request and response messages".

Comment: Or having re-read you question - maybe you knew all that already. I think that's the way to go, really.

Comment: Thanks David. I would mark the question as answered if you could reply :)